# Editable Telerik Radgrid loses editing when paging

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I am using Telerik Radgrid and it loads in edit mode to give excel  like editing feature to users. But when the user clicks on paging and does postback, the grid doesnt load in edit mode. I need editable in all the pages.

This is what I used to accomplish editable radgrid.

```
protected void rgStoreCosting_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtStoreCosting.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            rgStoreCosting.EditIndexes.Add(i);
        }
    }
```

When paging occurs, this event is no longer fired , hence not editing. Is there any other way to accomplish editing on paging. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing your code and attaching the editable code to the PreRender event:

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < RadGrid1.PageSize; count++)
    {
        RadGrid1.EditIndexes.Add(count);
    }

    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

---

[image]